# How to revert a commit and put changes back to stage

Tags: git, revert, changeset

How can I revert a commit but put the changes but on the stage so I can edit the commit until it is what I want.

Formerly I've been familar with TFS, where revert did exactly that, but in GIT `git revert` seem to automatically check-in the undone commit, so no chance to keep something from the changeset.

Comment: You could write `git reset --soft`, which will uncommit your changes and put them back in stage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *can* use `git revert -n`.  I would advise that you *don't*.  Make a separate commit to make the changes that you *do* want.

The reason for that is simple enough.  A commit *is* a snapshot, but it *represents* a change.  To find the change from the snapshot, Git compares the commit to its immediate parent.

That is, if file A had 10 lines before, and has 11 now, comparing the old copy of file A to the new copy of file A will (probably) show that someone added one line.  The diff will say: *to change the old commit to the new one, add this one line to file A*.  If file B had 20 lines before, and has 19 now, the diff will say: *to change the old commit to the new one, delete this one line from file B*.

A simple `git revert` that commits will, when shown, show the same change but backwards: *delete this one line from file A, and add this one line to file B.*

If what you *meant*—and will commit in this *third* commit—is to just add the one line to file *A*, now you have a correct *single commit* which, when shown, will say *add this one line to file A*.

If you instead make a non-committing revert, then put the line back, you'll have to add together two separate commits—the mistaken one, and the correcting revert—to see what was actually intended.  That's not *wrong*, but it means that anyone coming along later, to see what happened and what they might need to do in some similar situation, has to work harder.

Compare these instructions:

1. "Do X; wait, no, don't do X. Do Y."
2. "Do X. Then while undoing X, do Z."

Which would future-you prefer to see?

(Note that you can construct commit `Y` by doing:

```
git cherry-pick -n X
```

where X is the one that you reverted.  That way, you get all the changes, but can start undoing them.

Note also that `git revert -n` and `git cherry-pick -n` put everything into the staging area—that is, they do a `git add` on all the updated files.  There's no actual problem with that, but if you don't like it, you can run `git reset` to un-stage.)

Comment: This is a very valid argument if the original intention was to _keep_ the original commit and the reverted commit. However, I think the OP was suggesting to eradicate the original commit (X) entirely, in which case others would only ever see Y.

Comment: Should have also said: eradicating a commit introduces its own hazards! :-)

Comment: @MichaelSorens: Yes—though if you have never *sent* the commit anywhere (e.g., if it's private to your own repository and you never ran `git push`) it's safe. This is also where `git reset HEAD~1` or equivalent comes in, if the commit was the most recent one.

Answer (score 13):

Try this

```
git reset HEAD^
```

HEAD^ means the previous commit.

Comment: Note that this answers a very different question. This might be the question the OP *should* have asked! Resetting away a bogus commit is sometimes the best way to go. But it's not the same as making a new commit that undoes a bad one.

Answer (score 5):

```
(make sure that you have a clean working directory)
git revert <commit>
(accept commit message)
git reset HEAD^
```

This will make it so that you have local changes that could revert the commit if you accepted everything, but allows you to only choose a few lines to revert. You can also change to `git reset HEAD^ --soft` if you want to have the changes put in your staging area.

I agree with the other answer that it is probably better to revert a full commit if you are dealing with other people's history. I use this `revert + reset` often when I rebase and fix my own changes though.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this this actually worked for me to make my changes from commit to staged
git reset --soft HEAD^